# Problem with deploying an application to gcloud run

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, flask, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm deploying a Python Flask application that uses `Selenium`. But I'm having problems with `gcloud` run.
With the logs, apparently the error is in `gunicorn`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.6-bookworm

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED true

ENV APP_HOME /back-end
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```

I've already tried to change some things in t`he dockerfile`, however, when removing `$PORT`, it causes problems with route traffic.

I don't know what else to do, I'm accepting any help to move forward with my project.

Comment: Did you try to run your container locally to validate first the well working state of it?

Comment: yup, it works fine